# How to estimate the cumulative values of grid unique id values moving downstream based on flow direction path in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have input "Unique Id" for each grid cell as shown in the figure and another input of “flow direction” which tells what direction the grid is flowing. The value of the flow direction refers to the "unique ID". For example, if the flow direction is 5, it means it flows to the cell that has unique ID 5.
The flow only propagates in increasing number.

I would like to sum the values of the Unique Id along the flow direction. The output I am looking for is shown on the rightmost matrix “Cumulative”.
[image]

```
unqid = [1,5,4,0;0,6,7,12;0,0,10,13;0,0,0,0];
flowd = [5,7,7,0;0,7,13,13;0,0,13,13;0,0,0,0];
unqid(unqid==0)=nan;
flowd(flowd==0)=nan;

z = zeros(size(unqid));
for i=1:size(unqid,1)
    for j=1:size(unqid,2)
        idx = find(flowd==unqid(i,j));
        z(i,j) = unqid(i,j) + nansum(nansum(unqid(idx)));
    end
end
```

Comment: How do you get the grid `Flow direction`? Which way do you traverse the grid? Can you show what you've tried, and point out where you're stuck?

Comment: @ViG sorry for not putting in a clear way. I have included my trial script, it works for some grids but not for all. I am not sure why I am not getting similar output as shown in the figure. By the way, the flow direction is estimated separately in GIS interface. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue remaining is that your flows aren't propagated at all. 1 flows to 5, but then doesn't contribute further to 7 or 13.

Propagation is simple if you know it will only propagate in increasing numbers as you traverse the grid. In this case, your core above requires a simple modification - put z instead of unqid in the loop.

```
z(i,j) = unqid(i,j) + nansum(nansum(z(idx)));
```

If propagation is general (flow from say point (3,3) can go to (2,2) too), it gets more complicated. A good idea would be to take a clue from image processing world and research those techniques, you will likely find a much neater solution than the one below especially if you use toolboxes. A possible conceptually simple propagation recipe would be:
In the first step, `z = unqid;` In the next one, figure out the flows. Do the list of all unique flow destinations: `unqDest = unique(flowd(~isnan(flowd))`. You get `[5, 7, 13]`. Now do something like:

```
while ~isempty(unqDest) && tries < length(initialUnqDest) % Second condition makes it possible to exit if flows loop - values will be pointless anyway, it at least exits instead of being stuck in an infinite loop.
   tries = tries + 1;
   for i = length(unqDest) : -1 : 1
      %if unqDest depends only on known values, update z and unqDest. Else skip.
   end
end
```

Figuring out if `unqDest` depends on known values should be straightforward - just check which unqids correspond to the flowd. Flow to 5 depends on 1 as `flowd=5` is just on `(1,1)` and `unqid(1,1) = 1;`. 1 isn't on `unqDest` list, so 5 can be updated. Flow to 7 depends on 4, 5, 6. 5 is on `unqDest` list, can't be updated. Similar for flow to 13. 
Now flow to 5 gets removed and `unqDest` becomes 1 element shorter, having just 7 and 13. Plus the `z` gets updated:

```
z(flow destination) = z(flow destination) + sum(z(flow sources));
```

As shown in the pseudocode above, do this until unqDest runs out of elements. If you have some loops, this will never happen as unqDest won't get removed for the loop part, this is the reason for the second condition - after a fixed number of tries equal to the max possible steps (in each step you remove a single unqDest) you simply give up. In the end, you should check if unqDest is empty - if it is, your matrix should be correct, if it isn't you have loops in the flow.

Comment: Thanks, @Zizy Archer for your thorough answer. In my case, it only propagates in increasing number and the first code correction do the job.